# Python3 max function using value in defaultdict as key not working

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x

Suppose `model` is a `defaultdict`, and `num` is a `set`

```
>>> model
>>> defaultdict(<function <lambda> at 0x11076f758>, {1: 3, 2: 2, 4: 1})
>>> num
>>> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}
```

I want to get the item from `num` that has maximum value in `model`, and the following code works fine in `Python2`

```
>>> # python 2.7.6
>>> max(num, key=model.get)
>>> 1
```

But it doesn't work in `Python3`,

```
>>> # python 3.3.3
>>> max(num, key=model.get)
>>> TypeError: unorderable types: NoneType() > int()
```

I can use `max(num, key=lambda k:model[k])` to get it work in `Python3`, but if the item in `num` is not in the `model`, it will be added. This will modify `model`.

I am wondering why `model.get` doesn't work in `Python3`, and how can I do it without modifying `model`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `key=lambda x: model.get(x, 0)`.

`defaultdict.get` by default returns None if the item is not found.  Python 2 allows ordered comparisons (like less-than and greater-than) on different types, but Python 3 doesn't.  When Python 3 tries to find the max, it tries to see if the value for one key is greater than another.  If one of the values is None, it fails with the error you saw.  The solution is to make your key function return zero instead of None for missing values.

Comment: Another follow up question, why `Python 3` doesn't allow ordered comparisons on different types?

Comment: `float("-inf")` might be a better default value, since there aren't any integers less than that, but several are below `0`.

Comment: @mitchelllc: Basically, because they don't make sense.  Is None supposed to be greater or less than the number 1?  Is the string "Hello" greater or less than the list [3, 4]?  In Python 2 the answer was arbitrary and could lead to strange bugs.